# How to pass indexPath value from performSegue() to prepareForSegue()

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableView in a `SubMenuViewController`, when a user taps (using `didSelectRowAt`) on a cell and segues, I need to pass that cell to the next `UserInputViewController`,

Here is my code:

```
class SubMenuViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Properties and outlets

    var node: Node?
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //MARK: - View controller methods

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationItem.title = node?.value.rawValue

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SubMenuTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubMenuCell")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "userInput" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! UserInputViewController
            let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
            vc.node = node?.childenNode[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}

//MARK: UITableViewDataSource methods

extension SubMenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return node!.childCount
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubMenuCell", for: indexPath) as! SubMenuTableViewCell
        let desciptionModule = node?.childenNode[indexPath.row].value

        let description = Modules.description(module: desciptionModule!)

        cell.title.text = description.main
        cell.subtitle.text = description.sub

        return cell
    }
}

//MARK: - UITableViewDelegate methods

extension SubMenuViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 68
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        guard let selectedNode = node?.childenNode[indexPath.row] else {
            return
        }

        if selectedNode.isLeaveNode() {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "userInput", sender: indexPath)
        } else {
            let subMenuViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subMenu") as! SubMenuViewController
            subMenuViewController.node = selectedNode
            //let subMenuViewController = SubMenuViewController(node: selectedNode)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subMenuViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, in my `performSegue`, I passed in my `indexPath` into the sender, and I should expect to get it back in `prepareForSegue`, but I can't. Any suggestions guys?

Thanks

Comment: are you saying that this line `let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath` crash?

Comment: Did you try to store selected index path as a property in SubMenuViewController (when cell is selected) and then use it whenever you need (in prepareForSegue for example)?

Comment: @ArtKirillov that is a workaround, but his approach is valid and must work, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ReinierMelian, I don’t think this is a workaround. It’s working now and will be on any iOS version. We just declare some property for internal using in a view controller. We can add fileprivate (or even private since Swift 4 release) modificator for clarity.

Comment: Elaborate more than just `but I can't`. Your code looks valid, and there's a possibility that `segue` itself is not triggering.

Comment: Thank you guys for your inputs! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **my opinion** it isn't very good practice to pass the index path (or any other value that counts a s "data") as the `sender` argument; as its name suggests, it is intended for passing the object that sent the message (i.e., called the action method), in this case `self` (you could "relay" the original sender if your action method calls another action method instead, but that's off-topic here).

*As @sCha kindly pointed out in the comments, the Apple documentation on this method in particular, though, seems to leave room for doubt nevertheless. The parameter name sender clearly comes from the homonimous argument in all **control actions** that follow Cocoa's target/action pattern.*

**My suggestion:**

The best you can do I think is to **store** the index path in a **property** of your view controller:

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
```

...**set it** on `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`:

```
if selectedNode.isLeaveNode() {
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "userInput", sender: indexPath)
} else {
    self.selectedIndexPath = nil
    // ...
```

...and **retrieve it** (while resetting the property) in the `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` implementation of the target view controller:

```
if let vc = segue.source as? SubmenuViewController {
    if let indexPath = vc.selectedIndexPath {
        vc.selectedIndexPath = nil // (reset it, just to be safe)

        // Use indexPath...
    }    
}
```

Comment: I don't think using `sender` is a bad practice. Apple docs explains this `sender` as: **The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue.** You can send any information you want to initiate the segue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The "use to intiate the segue" part seems to reaffirm exactly what I said. The "object is made available for informational purposes" part is more ambiguous, I agree... Depends on what the "information" is (not limitted to "data passed around"). In any case, I made my remark in line with the historical sender argument common to all **control** actions (that's where the name comes I believe, even for `prepareForSegue()`)